# flatten a dictionary of dictionaries in to a list in python

Tags: python, mysql, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries and need to flatten it into a list. My goal here is to have it in a form that I can send to a MySQL database. The dictionary is in the form

```
{
 'Customer 1': 
   {'Vitamin A': 0, 'Calcium': 1, 'Protein': 1, 'B vitamins': 0, 'HPMR': 0},
 'Customer 2': 
   {'Vitamin A': 0, 'Calcium': 0, 'Protein': 1, 'B vitamins': 1, 'HPMR': 0}
 }
```

I want it to end up like:

```
('Customer 1', 'Vitamin A', 0), ('Customer 1', 'Calcium', 1)
...
('Customer 2', 'Vitamin A', 0), ('Customer 2', 'Calcium', 0)`
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dictio = {'Customer 1': {'Vitamin A': 0, 'Calcium': 1, 'Protein': 1, 'B vitamins': 0, 'HPMR': 0}, 'Customer 2': {'Vitamin A': 0, 'Calcium': 0, 'Protein': 1, 'B vitamins': 1, 'HPMR': 0}}
a = []
for key in dictio.keys():
    for key_ in dictio[key].keys():
        a.append((key,key_,dictio[key][key_]))

print a
```

Output:
`[('Customer 2', 'Calcium', 0), ('Customer 2', 'Vitamin A', 0), ('Customer 2', 'HPMR', 0), ('Customer 2', 'Protein', 1), ('Customer 2', 'B vitamins', 1), ('Customer 1', 'Calcium', 1), ('Customer 1', 'Vitamin A', 0), ('Customer 1', 'HPMR', 0), ('Customer 1', 'Protein', 1), ('Customer 1', 'B vitamins', 0)]`

Also what you are inserting are tuples to the list, not lists.

Answer (score 2):

```
customers = {'Customer 1': {'Vitamin A': 0, 
                            'Calcium': 1, 
                            'Protein': 1, 
                            'B vitamins': 0, 
                            'HPMR': 0}, 
             'Customer 2': {'Vitamin A': 0, 
                            'Calcium': 0, 
                            'Protein': 1, 
                            'B vitamins': 1, 
                            'HPMR': 0}}
all_orders = []
for customer, order in customers.items():
    customer_orders = [(customer, vitamin, quantity) for vitamin, quantity in order.items()]
    all_orders.append(customer_orders)

all_orders = [[('Customer 2', 'Calcium', 0),
               ('Customer 2', 'Vitamin A', 0),
               ('Customer 2', 'HPMR', 0),
               ('Customer 2', 'Protein', 1),
               ('Customer 2', 'B vitamins', 1)],
              [('Customer 1', 'Calcium', 1),
               ('Customer 1', 'Vitamin A', 0),
               ('Customer 1', 'HPMR', 0),
               ('Customer 1', 'Protein', 1),
               ('Customer 1', 'B vitamins', 0)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [6]: dic={'Customer 1': {'Vitamin A': 0, 'Calcium': 1, 'Protein': 1, 'B vitamins': 0, 'HPMR': 0}, 'Customer 2': {'Vitamin A': 0, 'Calcium': 0, 'Protein': 1, 'B vitamins': 1, 'HPMR': 0}}

In [7]: [tuple([x]+list(y)) for x in dic for y in dic[x].items() ]

Out[7]: 
[('Customer 2', 'Calcium', 0),
 ('Customer 2', 'Vitamin A', 0),
 ('Customer 2', 'HPMR', 0),
 ('Customer 2', 'Protein', 1),
 ('Customer 2', 'B vitamins', 1),
 ('Customer 1', 'Calcium', 1),
 ('Customer 1', 'Vitamin A', 0),
 ('Customer 1', 'HPMR', 0),
 ('Customer 1', 'Protein', 1),
 ('Customer 1', 'B vitamins', 0)]
```

or using `itertools.chain()`:

```
In [8]: from itertools import chain

In [9]: [tuple(chain(*([x],y))) for x in dic for y in dic[x].items() ]
Out[9]: 
[('Customer 2', 'Calcium', 0),
 ('Customer 2', 'Vitamin A', 0),
 ('Customer 2', 'HPMR', 0),
 ('Customer 2', 'Protein', 1),
 ('Customer 2', 'B vitamins', 1),
 ('Customer 1', 'Calcium', 1),
 ('Customer 1', 'Vitamin A', 0),
 ('Customer 1', 'HPMR', 0),
 ('Customer 1', 'Protein', 1),
 ('Customer 1', 'B vitamins', 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[(k, k2, v) for k in dct for k2, v in k.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I too thought of a list comprehension like others:

```
cust = {'Customer 1': {'Vitamin A': 0, 'Calcium': 1, 'Protein': 1, 'B vitamins': 0, 'HPMR': 0}, 'Customer 2': {'Vitamin A': 0, 'Calcium': 0, 'Protein': 1, 'B vitamins': 1, 'HPMR': 0}}
cust_flat = [ (k, k2, v2) for k2, v2 in v.iteritems() for k, v in cust.iteritems() ]
```

Result looks like:

```
[('Customer 2', 'Calcium', 1),
 ('Customer 1', 'Calcium', 1),
 ('Customer 2', 'Vitamin A', 0),
 ('Customer 1', 'Vitamin A', 0),
 ('Customer 2', 'HPMR', 0),
 ('Customer 1', 'HPMR', 0),
 ('Customer 2', 'Protein', 1),
 ('Customer 1', 'Protein', 1),
 ('Customer 2', 'B vitamins', 0),
 ('Customer 1', 'B vitamins', 0)]
```